# How do I render all DOM elements in a list found in props?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to render a bunch of HTML elements found in an object. I have tried a few methods on this site, but for some reason they don't seem to work, i'm not quite sure why.

Essentially I am trying to render all of the elements in an array... 0 --> array.length - 1:

```
    render(){

    let allGameLines = this.props.allGameLines;
    // allGameLines looks like [<GameLine />, <GameLine />, <GameLine /> ... <GameLine />]

    return(

        <div id = "allGameLines">
            allGameLines[0]
            allGameLines[1]
            allGameLines[2]
            ...
            ...
            ...
            allGameLines[allGameLines.length - 1]
        </div>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (  
 <div> {this.props.allGameLines.length && this.props.allGameLines.map(item => (
     <div> {item} </div> 
    )
  )} 
 </div>
)
```

In order to display the elements of an array use `array.map`

Comment: This worked very well, the only change I had to make was to render them only once, as gameLines can be deleted (causing the number 0 to be rendered when there are no gameLines left).